# Having trouble converting a character value to an integer value

Tags: java, arrays, char, integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class baseConverter {
//Main method
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    System.out.println("What number base would you like to convert?");
    int base = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Checking if the base is between 2 and 9, inclusive
    if (base >= 2 && base <=9){
        System.out.println("Please enter a base " + base + " number:");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter a base from 2 to 9");
    }
    input = keyboard.next();
    int converted = compute(input, base);
    System.out.println("The base-10 conversion of that number is " + converted);
}
//Where all the conversion will take place
public static int compute(String userString, int userBase){
    int n = userString.length(), output = 0;
    int[] num = new int[n];

    //The for loop that does all the computing
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        //assigning values to the array indeces
        num[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(userString.charAt(i-1)));
        if(num[i-1] != 0){
            output = output + ((userBase ^ (n-i)) * (num[i-1]-1));
        }else{
            output = output;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("User base is " + userBase+ ". n is "+ n);
    return output;
    }
}
```

When I run this and input the base and 3 and the input as 2, it seems to convert the value '2' to it's ASCII value of 50 when storing it in the num array. I guess my question is if there is any way that I could work around this or what an entirely different way of getting the value from the string stored as an integer.

Comment: Why don't you do `input = keyboard.nextInt()` instead? So that `input` is already an `int`. This way you don't have to use `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: The purpose of this program is to convert any number from any number system into a base 10 number. It won't just be taking single digit numbers so I thought that maybe taking it in as a String would make it easier to single out each number and therefore make the conversion easier. Is there any way to grab the length of an integer or isolate the values of an integer without turning them into characters first?

Comment: You're best bet is what you're doing already with `String.charAt` if you want to isolate single digits. What's the line that's converting 2 to 50?

Comment: When I set up the breakpoints around

    `num[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(userString.charAt(i-1)));`

It looks like the number being stored in the array is the ASCII value of 2 instead of just being the number 2

Comment: I just tried running your example and I'm not seeing what you're describing. Can you show me what your input is for when it asks `What number base would you like to convert?` and `Please enter a base from 2 to 9` along with what you expect the result to be.

Comment: With that line you gave me, when I input 3 for the number base and then just 2 for the number, I get an output of 6 when it should be 2  (because (3^0)*2=2). It looks like the conversion is fine now but the math is wrong but I should be able to figure that out.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the equation `output = output + ((userBase ^ (n-i)) * (num[i-1]-1));` Also, did you mean to use `Math.pow()`? `^` does not mean "to the power of" in java.